# Haskell function to uppercase the first letter and lowercase the rest of the letters in a word

Tags: function, haskell

I have been trying to write a function that capitalizes the first letter and uncapitalized the rest in Haskell. For example, capitalized "mELboURNe" == "Melbourne" but I am getting errors. I have to use list comprehension.

I have tried this,

```
capitilized :: String -> String 
capitilized = map(\x -> if length x == 1 then capitilized3 x else capitilized2 x) 

capitilized2 :: Char -> Char
capitilized2 x= Char.toLower x

capitilized3 :: Char -> Char
capitilized3 x= Char.toUpper x
```

But I am getting this error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘t0 a0’ with actual type ‘Char’
    • In the first argument of ‘length’, namely ‘x’
      In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘length x’
      In the expression: length x == 1
   |
21 | capitilized = map(\x -> if length x == 1 then capitilized3 x else capitilized2 x)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You seem to think `length` will return the position of `x` within the original string.

Comment: Please note that `capitilized2 x= Char.toLower x` is equivalent to writing `capitilized2 = Char.toLower` which should make you wonder why you're bothering to give these functions _less_ meaningful names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `String` is a *list* of `Char`s, but a `Char` is not a list so `length x` makes no sense.

You can work with pattern matching with:

```
capitilized :: String -> String 
capitilized [] = …
capitilized (x:xs) = …
```

Here especially the second pattern is important since `x` will bind with the *first* `Char`acter of the string, and `xs` with the remaining characters. I leave the `…` parts as an exercise.